# Delete generated elements from div angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to delete the criteria list item on clicking the delete button. Right now only the filter is getting refreshed. The tables are not being deleted. Suggestions to get through this.

- HTML

  ```
     <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li style="display: inline-block" ng-repeat="crtia in newCriteria" >
      <table>
        <tr>

          <td>
            <select class="input-sm" ng-model="crtia.name" ng-options="searchopt for searchopt in searchcriteria " ng-click="searchy.check()"></select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="input-sm " ng-model="crtia.value" placeholder="{{crtia.name}}" ng-change="newList()" ng-click="searchy.check()" />
          </td>
          <td>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" aria-label="Left Align" ng-click="removeCriteria($index)">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true" ></span>
          </button>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ```
- JS

  ```
       $scope.removeCriteria=function($index){
        $scope.searchy.check();
        alert($index);
       $scope.newCriteria.splice($index,1);
        $scope.newList();         //Refreshes the filter
      }
  ```

Comment: plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/3yOmiIJ9Yu9RfAgmuVA7

Comment: i am fixing your problem wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" aria-label="Left Align" data-ng-click="removeCriteria(crtia)">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.removeCriteria = function (sourceToRemove) {
    $scope.searchy.check();

    var index = $scope.newCriteria.indexOf(sourceToRemove);
    $scope.newCriteria.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.newList();         //Refreshes the filter
}
```

Update [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ytcYZ2wfOv7UdYGzqLyI?p=preview)

Comment: Object index and ng repeat index both are different